# WPF Setter Target binding to button content's name

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've built a `ControlTemplate` that I'm using for all my buttons within a window, but there is one that needs an extra trigger that when raised changes it's contents value.
Obviously I don't want to add this trigger onto the control template as it would effect all the other buttons that use this same control template. So what I'm trying to do is add the data trigger onto the buttons specific style and then reference the content name and change it directly within the style which I assumed would be easy.

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="34"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Height="30"
        Padding="0"
        Click="OnMaximiseClick">
     <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximised">
                     <Setter TargetName="MaxPath"
                             Property="Data"
                             Value="F1M0,10L0,3 3,3 3,0 10,0 10,2 4,2 4,3 7,3 7,6 6,6 6,5 1,5 1,10z M1,10L7,10 7,7 10,7 10,2 9,2 9,6 6,6 6,9 1,9z" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </Button.Style>

     <Path x:Name="MaxPath"
           Width="10"
           Height="10"
           Data="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,8 1,3z"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
           Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
</Button>
```

The issue lies in that the `Setter` is unable to access the `TargetName="MaxPath"`, I've also tried `{Binding ElementName=MaxPath}` but I've hit an impasse. I know that I could build up the `ControlTemplate` again within the buttons style but it has numerous triggers that I don't fancy maintaining within two places and I'm sure that there must be a way to do this quickly and easily but I just can't see it.

Is there anyway of referencing the button content within it's `Style` or will I have to rebuild the `Path` within that `Buttons` `ControlTemplate` and then redefine all my `Triggers` within this new `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Instead of changing `Path.Data` simply have 2 `Path`s and switch their visibility. It's strange what you are trying to do some visual changes inside minimized window, because you will see nothing.

Comment: @Sinatr how would this work? As I can't access my existing `Path` from the `Setter` how would I access the other `Path`? The window won't be minimised, I've accidentally written `Minimised` instead of `Maximised`, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Sinatr Sorry, I think I know what you mean. Have 2 triggers that monitor the state of the window then change the content of the button when these are triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From second thought you don't need `DataTrigger`. Simply bind 2 `Path` to window state directly. You will need reusable converter though.

Below is a demo (make button clickable and add bindings to `Fill`):

xaml:

```
<Button>
    <Grid Width="10"
          Height="10">
        <Path Fill="Black"
              Data="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,8 1,3z"
              Visibility="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource=RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, ConverterParameter=Invert, Converter={local:StateToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Path Fill="Black"
              Data="F1M0,10L0,3 3,3 3,0 10,0 10,2 4,2 4,3 7,3 7,6 6,6 6,5 1,5 1,10z M1,10L7,10 7,7 10,7 10,2 9,2 9,6 6,6 6,9 1,9z"
              Visibility="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Converter={local:StateToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

converter:

```
public class StateToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public StateToVisibilityConverter() { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = (WindowState)value == WindowState.Maximized;
        if ((string)parameter == "Invert")
            result = !result;
        return result ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

---

From third thought (xaml only):

```
<Button>
    <Path Fill="Black"
          Width="10"
          Height="10">
        <Path.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Path">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Data"
                            Value="F1M0,10L0,3 3,3 3,0 10,0 10,2 4,2 4,3 7,3 7,6 6,6 6,5 1,5 1,10z M1,10L7,10 7,7 10,7 10,2 9,2 9,6 6,6 6,9 1,9z" />
                </Style.Setters>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                 Value="Maximized">
                        <Setter Property="Data"
                                Value="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,1 1,3z" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>
</Button>
```

Comment: Perfect, I just finished up doing exactly what you done in your third example when I seen your answer, think this is the best method of doing this. I'd give you a high five but unfortunately the screens in the way.

Comment: Last one is good if you need it in just one place (quick and dirty). But I actually like the one with converters more. Notice how easy to add, remove and maintain first example. You just need to write bunch of converters once ... and learn MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a ControlTemplate:

```
<Button 
     ... [your other properties here] >

        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path x:Name="MaxPath"
                    Width="10"
                   Height="10"
                   Data="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,8 1,3z"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Minimised">
                        <Setter TargetName="MaxPath"
                         Property="Data"
                         Value="F1M0,10L0,3 3,3 3,0 10,0 10,2 4,2 4,3 7,3 7,6 6,6 6,5 1,5 1,10z M1,10L7,10 7,7 10,7 10,2 9,2 9,6 6,6 6,9 1,9z" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

You can add other triggers if you want..

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. As my existing control template has numerous triggers on it I don't want to have to maintain them to two separate places unfortunately.